# Unique readability showing an $\mathcal{L}$-formula

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

**Question**: Show the string $$\forall v_1\forall v_2(Pv_1\rightarrow Pv_2\rightarrow\equiv fv_1v_2c)$$ is not an $\mathcal{L}$-formula

**Answer**: Assume for contradiction that $\forall v_1\forall v_2(Pv_1\rightarrow Pv_2\rightarrow\equiv fv_1v_2c)$ is an $\mathcal{L}$-formula

$(1)$ By unique readability twice, we have that $(Pv_1\rightarrow Pv_2\rightarrow\equiv fv_1v_2c)$ is an $\mathcal{L}$-formula

$...$ etc

**Contention**: How does the unique readability theorem show it is an $\mathcal{L}$-formula?

Does it deduce it from eliminating the $\forall v_1$ and $\forall v_2$ before the brackets,

or is it from comprising what is in the brackets to make up the $\mathcal{L}$-formula

(I am suspecting the former, but I would like some clarification)

I can see that $(Pv_1)$, $(Pv_2)$ and $(\equiv fv_1v_2c)\in AtFml_\mathcal{L}$

I would just like some clarrification on how the unique readability theorem works for $\mathcal{L}$-formulas

Comment: You have to rewiew the syntax rules ... But why $(≡fv_1v_2c)$ ? It is in prefix notation ? If so, also the conditionals must be in prefix form ...

Comment: I don't understand, what is wrong with $(\equiv fv_1v_2c)$?

Comment: I mean that if the offical syntax is in prefix form, then $P \to Q$ must be $\to P Q$.

Comment: Good point, but in the extract I took this from, I guess at some stage we have supposed that $\equiv$ is a predicate symbol and $\rightarrow$ is a formula building operation. I guess assume that this is the case for the problem.

Comment: I think the key to solving requires knowledge of your language and its grammar. My guess is $(\equiv fv_1v_2c)$ is not a wff according to your rules, but your hypothesis asserts every subformula is a wff.

Comment: Another possibility is that the chain of $\rightarrow$ is ambiguous, and your WFFs require unique readability. This may or may not be the case, again, depending on your grammar rules.

Comment: @Jonny The proof does deduce that $\rightarrow$ is ambiguous and therefore not an $\mathcal{L}$-formula, but my question is to get through step $(1)$ of the answer, do we reduce to this by unique readability from our initial assumption or build this up by unique readability? (I'm suspecting the former)

Comment: @Jonny What is wff? well founded formula?

Comment: A wff is a well formed formula; a string of symbols in the language that also follows all the grammatical rules.

Comment: In order to aplly the Unique readibility Th, we have to follow the detailed syntactical specifications, avoiding to omit parentheses. If so, a consequence of the Theorem is that **no proper initial part of a formula is a formula**. If you apply this result to your example, you will find that (after removing the quantifiers) the part $Pv_1 \to Pv_2$ is a formula, contradicting the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a language/grammar with unique readability, a well formed formula has only one unique parse tree.

In many languages the infix notation $\varphi_1 \rightarrow \varphi_2 \rightarrow \varphi_3$ has unique readability by convention, but apparently in your language this is not the case. It is easy to see the ambiguity by converting to prefix notation. One parsing is $\rightarrow( \varphi_1, \rightarrow(\varphi_2, \varphi_3)) $, while the other is $\rightarrow( \rightarrow(\varphi_1, \varphi_2),  \varphi_3)$.

Since you assumed that your string was well formed, it should have unique readability. Since we have shown that it does not, we have found a contradiction and your assumption must not be correct.